# Ubuntu compiling kernel module first time

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, makefile, linux-kernel

I'm trying to compile a simple kernel module for the first time:

```
#include <linux/module.h>    
#include <linux/kernel.h>

int init_nodule(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world1.\n");
        return 0;
}
void cleanup_module(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye\n");
}
```

I've used `obj-m += hello-1.o` (that's the name of the module) but i'm getting an error:

> obj−m: command not found

Why is this happening? I tried looking online for a solution, but nothing I found helped..

**EDIT:** After modifying based on @Mathieu answer , I get the following error :

```sh
> make -C /lib/modules/4.18.0-15-generic/build M=/home/galco modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic'
Makefile:970: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
scripts/Makefile.build:45: /home/galco/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/galco/Makefile'.  Stop.
Makefile:1534: recipe for target '_module_/home/galco' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/galco] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic'
makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Could you post your makefile entirely? And how do you launch the build?

Comment: I simply run that command from the ubuntu terminal..  And what do you mean how do I launch the build? @Mathieu

Comment: See my answer, the line `obj-m:...` is a `make` directive...

Comment: *please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel*

Comment: @CacahueteFrito I did, but now it says it can't find Makefile file ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `obj-m += hello-1.o` must be put in a file named `Makefile`

So it will looks like:

```
obj-m += hello-1.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:  
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

To launch the build process, just execute `make` from your command line.

More resource: https://qnaplus.com/how-to-compile-linux-kernel-module/

Comment: Thank you, I now get another error.. can you look at the edit I've made?

Comment: @Galco Did you read the error message? It’d fairly explicit and descriptive in what you need to do.

Comment: Sorry, I've downloaded the libelf-dev but now it says that it can't find the Makefile file..

Comment: @Galco Did you save the above as `/home/galco/Makefile`?

Comment: @Galco your file must be name `Makefile` not `makefile`

Comment: Thanks , beginner mistakes :)